# TensorFlow first attempt, bad results

Tags: tensorflow

I can't solve my problem, help me please. It's my first attempt of neural networks, i tried to make nn which can check is number betwen (3:6) or not. I used several docs in internet and make some listing. But it has not working results. It's always "not in (3:6)". And I can't to understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
#Is number between (3:6)
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random

def is_num_between(num):
    right_border = 6
    left_border = 3
    if num < right_border and num > left_border:
        return 1
    return 0

def is_num_around(num):
    right_border = 6
    left_border = 3
    if num <= left_border or num >= right_border:
        return 1
    return 0

def init_weights(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape, stddev=0.01))

def model(X, w_h, w_o):
    h = tf.nn.tanh(tf.matmul(X, w_h))
    return tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(h, w_o))

def included_or_not(i, prediction):
    return [str(i) + " is in (3:6)", str(i) + " not in (3:6)"][prediction]

NUM_COUNT = 2
NUM_HIDDEN = 10
BATCH_SIZE = 10000

pre_trX = [np.random.random_sample() * 10 for i in range(100000)]
pre_trY1 = [is_num_between(i) for i in pre_trX]
pre_trY2 = [is_num_around(i) for i in pre_trX]

trX = np.array([np.array([pre_trX[i], 1]) for i in range(len(pre_trX))])
trY = np.array([np.array([pre_trY1[i], pre_trY2[i]]) for i in range(len(pre_trX))])


# print(type(trX))
# print(pre_trX)
# print(pre_trY1)
# print(pre_trY2)
# print(trX[0])
# exit()

X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, NUM_COUNT])
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 2])

w_h = init_weights([NUM_COUNT, NUM_HIDDEN])
w_o = init_weights([NUM_HIDDEN, 2])

py_X = model(X, w_h, w_o)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(py_X, Y))
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)

predict_op = tf.argmax(py_X, 1)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()

    for epoch in range(200):
        p = np.random.permutation(range(len(trX)))
        trX, trY = trX[p], trY[p]

        for start in range(0, len(trX), BATCH_SIZE):
            end = start + BATCH_SIZE
            sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: trX[start:end], Y: trY[start:end]})

        print(epoch, np.mean(np.argmax(trY, axis=1) ==
                         sess.run(predict_op, feed_dict={X: trX, Y: trY})))


    # Tipo natrenirovana, nado ee potestit
    def check_nnetwork():
        numbers = [np.array([np.random.random_sample()*10, 1])]
        teX = np.array(numbers)
        teY = sess.run(predict_op, feed_dict={X: teX})
        output = np.vectorize(included_or_not)("%.3f" % numbers[0][0], teY)
        print(output)

    for i in range(40):
        check_nnetwork()
```

Answer (score 0):

What does your loss function look like?
Also how many positive examples are there compared to negative examples? If the data is too skewed it might learn to just always predict negative as that is what minimizes the loss function.

The other issue might be that there is a fundamental problem with your architecture in that you expect a one-level neural network to learn a non-linear function which isn't actually possible.